# Java 8 ZoneDateTime getting time

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime

I am trying to update this code to use Java 8 time api

```
  Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    c.set(2020, 6 - 1, 7, 0, 0, 0);
    Date dts = c.getTime();
    // this time is already initialised to 01:00 BST
    int hours = 24;
    int minutes= 9;
    int seconds=0;

    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.setTime(dts);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);

    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    // Mon Jun 08 01:09:00 BST 2020
```

to something like this

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020,6,7,0,0,0,0,ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    zdt.withHour(hours-1);
    zdt.withMinute(minutes);
    zdt.plusSeconds(seconds);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

First thing is ZonedDate time unlike The Gregorian Calender doesnt initalise at 1 o clock.  Which is where im having difficulties.

ZonedDateTime also doesnt take hours more than 23 so i have to reduce it by 1.

I guess the question im asking is what are the java alternatives to the methods in the gregorian calender that can exhibit similar behaviour.

Comment: _this code prints_ : in the timezone where you print that; _The problem is from a scheduling point of view_ : ZonedDateTime would be a poor choice for scheduling, since it always depends on the zone

Comment: "My understanding is that the time given is always UTC" is wrong. It gives you the exact local time. The offset part informs you that the shown time has the given offset from UTC.

Comment: @Eugene i have changed the question to reflect the discussion

Comment: Are you trying to create a `ZonedDateTime` instance that stores the timestamp 8th June 2020 at 1:08 [a.m.] ?

Answer (score 1):

The instances of LocalTime, LocalDate, LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime are inmutable. Just like you do with your strings, you have to override the reference to the object with the new instance every time you make a change:

```
   ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020,6,7,0,0,0,0,ZoneId.of("UTC"));

   zdt = zdt.withHour(hours-1);
   zdt = zdt.withMinute(minutes);
   zdt = zdt.plusSeconds(seconds);
   System.out.println(zdt);
```

If you are new to this API, I would recommend you to not use the Zoned classes unless it is absolutely necessary, as they are very error prone.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Huatxu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469680/1398418) use `plusHours` instead of `withHour` and use it with your local time zone and format string:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
int hours = 24;
int minutes = 9;
int seconds = 0;

zdt = zdt.plusHours(hours);
zdt = zdt.withMinute(minutes);
zdt = zdt.plusSeconds(seconds);

System.out.println(zdt
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu")));
```

Or explicitly to get "BST" anywhere:

```
System.out.println(zdt
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu")));
```

Comment: The problem with using localdate and i might be wrong.  The app im working on is accesbile worldwide.  the servers are typically aws servers around the globe.  So when we work out the times using system time wont work.  We have a config which knows the timezone information for each user.  and we can essentially use that to give them the timing for there zone that is offset to UTC.  

Hera corrected my understanding of what i was observing with zoneddatetime which was essentially the core of the issue

Answer (score 1):

It turns out what i needed was similar to this

```
 ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(),ZoneId.of("UTC")).withHour(0).withMinute(minutes)
        .withSecond(seconds).plusHours(hours);

result = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
```

Thanks all for helping me get to this point.